# Install phpMyAdmin with apt-get

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, php, phpmyadmin

I want to Install phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu 16.04,

I'm trying to do that by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gett
```

But, I have an error with this command like:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php-gett
```

What should I do?

Comment: Did you mean `php-gettext` instead of `php-gett`?

Answer (score 1):

Type:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext
```